# Where is the setting for metering mode located under the D90 menu?

Tags: nikon-d90, camera-controls

I own a Nikon D90 Camera. I know that I can select one of the metering modes by using the metering button provided on top of the camera. However, I would like to know under which menu item do these metering modes appear when I click on the menu button located on the back of the camera?

Comment: Check the camera manual. All menu options are listed there. Intuitively, it should be called 'Metering'.

Comment: This seems like one of those questions where the *real* question is disguised.  Since you know a quick and easy way to change it with the button, why do you want a menu option?

Comment: @ahockley: There are some people who are curious to know things that are not documented well. I am one of them :-)

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot change the metering mode via the menu.  You can't change exposure compensation, shutter speed and aperture, and most other things that have special buttons or dials setup for them.

The menus are more for specialised and detailed settings.  For example there is a dial for setting the self timer on/off, but a menu option to set the self timer delay and number of shots (which has many choices unsuitable for a simple dial).  There is a button/dial for white balance, but a menu to fine tune the white balance presets.  And so on.

Most anything you might need to frequently change has a convenient button or dial, and litte or nothing is then duplicated in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Thought this would be easy...  press Menu, scroll up/down the left hand column to "CUSTOM SETTING MENU", press OK, scroll up/down to item (b) Metering/Exposure, press OK...  and it's not there!

I believe I have just gone through all the menus and couldn't find it, is that possible?  Maybe you can only change the metering mode via the dedicated button and the scroll wheel?